# Join Datasources on Form

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

From Accounts payable > Periodic > Maintain vendor invoices > Vendor invoice > From product receipt, I can open `PurchJournalSelect_PackingSlip` form.

I need to add a column with the vendor name.

As far as I see, we are using the table `VendPackingSlipJour` and a relation with the `VendTable` is there by default:

[image]

Going to `VendTable`, we can find the relation with `DirPartyTable`:

[image]

Now comes the part that doesn't work.

I have tried to add both `VendTable` and `DirPartyTable` to the DataSource list in `PurchJournalSelect_PackingSlip` form.

1. `VendTable` with: -  **JoinSource**: `VendPackingSlipJour` and **Link Type**: InnerJoin.
2. `DirPartyTable` with: - **JoinSource**: `VendTable` and **Link Type**: InnerJoin.

And the last thing was to drag the Name field from `DirPartyTable` to the grid. Seems nice but I get an empty column. What am I doing wrong ? I know I could add a display method but that not allow the user to filter on this column..

Comment: Do you want the vendor name in the Overview grid or in the All grid (which is displayed first after opening the form)? Please note that the Overview grid uses the `VendPackingSlipJour` datasource while the All grid uses the `VendPackingSlipJourAll` datasource. Your description would be the way if you want to show the vendor name in the Overview grid.

Comment: @FH-Inway, I did it and you were right. I had to change VendPackingSlipJour with VendPackingSlipJourAll. The DataSource of the Grid in cause was VendPackingSlipJourAll. You can transform your comment intro an answer and I will accept it to close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the Overview grid in form `PurchJournalSelect_PackingSlip` uses the `VendPackingSlipJour` datasource while the All grid uses the `VendPackingSlipJourAll` datasource. You should change the join source of the `VendTable` datasource to `VendPackingSlipJourAll`.